# The application shows a white screen forever. cordova ios@6.1.0

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

**Problem**

I'm using cordova ios@6.1.0, but the application shows a white screen forever when I build my Ionic 5 app. Could anyone suggest please, if exist way to fix it ?

**What is expected to happen?**

The application's screen keeps white.

**Information from xcode**

```
020-07-28 11:50:07.960630+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] ADAL version 2.3.1
2020-07-28 11:50:08.158368+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] Apache Cordova native platform version 6.1.0 is starting.
2020-07-28 11:50:08.158707+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2020-07-28 11:50:08.241162+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2020-07-28 11:50:08.246238+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] The preference key "KeyboardResize" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-07-28 11:50:08.246539+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] The preference key "AutoInjectCordova" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-07-28 11:50:08.246717+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] The preference key "AudioCanMix" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-07-28 11:50:08.375819+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] The preference key "WKSuspendInBackground" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-07-28 11:50:08.376166+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] The preference key "MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-07-28 11:50:09.129646+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process EzParts
2020-07-28 11:50:09.129963+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-07-28 11:50:09.130467+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-07-28 11:50:09.188180+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] The preference key "KeyboardAppearanceDark" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-07-28 11:50:09.188642+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] The preference key "AllowLinkPreview" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-07-28 11:50:09.188934+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] The preference key "AllowBackForwardNavigationGestures" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-07-28 11:50:09.189114+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2020-07-28 11:50:09.190014+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] Using Ionic WKWebView
2020-07-28 11:50:09.190808+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] [CDVTimer][console] 0.118017ms
2020-07-28 11:50:09.191149+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.131011ms
2020-07-28 11:50:09.194027+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 2.695918ms
2020-07-28 11:50:09.194393+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.123024ms
2020-07-28 11:50:09.267337+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] [CDVTimer][file] 72.758913ms
2020-07-28 11:50:09.275284+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6000033af9c0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2020-07-28 11:50:09.293255+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] [CDVTimer][backgroundmode] 25.712967ms
2020-07-28 11:50:09.293514+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] [CDVTimer][backgroundmode] 0.010014ms
2020-07-28 11:50:09.294796+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] [CDVTimer][inappbrowser] 1.090050ms
2020-07-28 11:50:09.295679+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] The preference key "KeyboardResize" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-07-28 11:50:09.295876+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
2020-07-28 11:50:09.296039+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] The preference key "HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-07-28 11:50:09.296910+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] The preference key "KeyboardAppearanceDark" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-07-28 11:50:09.297412+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] [CDVTimer][cdvionickeyboard] 2.382994ms
2020-07-28 11:50:09.297608+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 107.020020ms
2020-07-28 11:50:16.451481+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] IAB.close() called but it was already closed.
2020-07-28 11:50:17.290529+0300 EzParts[5114:415617] Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 284 ms
```

**Version information**

```
Ionic CLI : 6.10.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 5.3.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
@angular-devkit/schematics : 8.1.3
@angular/cli : 8.1.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 2.2.0
```

**Cordova:**

```
Cordova CLI : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : ios 6.1.0
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 22 other plugins)
```

**Utility:**

```
cordova-res : not installed
native-run : not installed
```

**System:**

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
ios-sim : 8.0.2
NodeJS : v12.15.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm : 6.14.7
OS : macOS Catalina
Xcode : Xcode 11.6 Build version 11E708
```

**Ionic plugin list:**

```
com-sarriaroman-photoviewer 1.2.4 "PhotoViewer"
cordova-clipboard 1.3.0 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.4.0 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.2 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.3 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-opener2 3.0.0 "File Opener2"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 4.0.1-dev "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-ms-adal 0.10.1 "ADAL for Cordova"
cordova-plugin-ms-adal-fork 0.10.4 "ADAL for Cordova"
cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.3.2 "NativeStorage"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-printer 0.8.0 "Printer"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 3.1.1 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.2.1 "Cordova WKWebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-zip 3.1.0 "cordova-plugin-zip"
cordova-sqlite-storage 4.0.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 5.0.2 "Diagnostic"
```

Answer (score 2):

cordova-ios 6 integrated the splash screen plugin into the platform, so if you were using ionic-native to hide the splash, it won't work because it relies in the plugin and the plugin is not installed on iOS.

Change `this.splashScreen.hide();` to `(navigator as any).splashscreen.hide();` in `app.component.ts`